# How to place Shiny panel output near mouse but on a DT Table?

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm creating a Shiny app using shinydashboard and I want to have a sort of tooltip pop up with dynamic information near the mouse when I hover over cells in a table which is being displayed using DT datatable and renderdatatable.

This other question: [How to place shiny panel near the pointer/mouse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39346273/how-to-place-shiny-panel-near-the-pointer-mouse) works well but it seems to be tied to the hoverOpts function within plotOutput. I'm looking to have mine work similar to this.

I believe that this could be achieved by using JavaScript or HTML to track the mouse position and then feed that into absolutePanel.

This post: [Javascript - Track mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position) seems to have some good information but with little knowledge of the JS language it is hard to understand.

I have tried using shinyBS as well but it doesn't seem to have the ability to dynamically update the tooltip.

ALTERNATIVE: 
Have the panel show up in one of two fixed positions but on top of the table rather than on the side. Is it possible to have Shiny panels overlap?